# How to change font-size of embed text

Tags: javascript, html, css, embed

I have the following code in my html document:

```html
<embed src="https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/iso_8859-1.txt" style="width:100%; height: 100%;font-size:1.2em">
```

Above code grabs a `txt` file locally, then display its contents in html. The problem is that I am unable to change the font size. Here is what I have tried

- wrapping (i.e., `<p><embed src="..."></p>`) and defining a css attribute for the wrapper.
- defining inner style (i.e., `<embed style="font-size:1.2em">`
- defining css for embed (i.e., `embed { font-size: 1.2em }`)

None of these work. Please help?

Comment: @ikiK — "HTML embed does not take style attributes" — Yes, it does. "as quick google search will show" — While W3Schools is generally *awful*, in this case it is correct. It says that "The `<embed>` tag also supports the Global Attributes in HTML." (with `style` being one of them).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can do this. The only properties allowed on embed are src, type, height and width (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/embed). It will work similarly to an iframe, so it's an isolated #document inside your tag:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

div {font-size: 3em;}
div font {font-size: inherit;}
It will change the embed text size but some it doesn't work on some editors. Hope it'll helpful